# Why angle brackets will not recognized by eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio

We are using comments like this in eclipse (zend studio):

```
/**
 * @return array<ObjectXY>
 */
public function moo() {
  // returns array of objectxy
}
```

Now if I want to use method moo, I write:

```
$myobj->moo();
```

And then, if I hover with mouse above `moo` I get the following output in the comment box:

```
@return array
```

Where is the "ObjectXY" after array? 
Why is it missing?
Can I configure this in eclipse (zend studio)?

Thank you.

EDIT: I see in stackoverflow strings within angle brackets do not be shown as well.

Answer (score 0):

Those comments (Javadoc style) can contain HTML content. So angle bracketed words are used for marking up the comment.

If you woul like the output itself to contain these brackets, use the `@code` notation:

```
/**
 * @return {@code array<ObjectXY>}
 */
```

This is naturally used for really displaying code snippets (and your example is one). The comment's return tag is usually for providing textual information, such as

```
/**
 * @return an {@code array<ObjectXY>} containing ...
 */
```

---

**UPDATE** as my first approach was slightly wrong.

As you are using the Zend Studio IDE for developping PHP applications, this style of comments is not called Javadoc, but [PHPDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc).

The statement that angle bracketed words are used for marking up, is still correct. But the solution seems to be wrong. In Javadoc, the `@code` notation is a relatively new one. Before it was `<code>...</code>`. Unfortunately this alone will not show the bracketed word. It must go along with `<pre>...</pre>` (or you should maybe use `pre` alone). Maybe this works:

```
/**
 * @return an <code><pre>array<ObjectXY></pre></code> containing ...
 */
```

Comment: Hello! You must be wrong.. Even if I copy your comment snippet into my comment eclipse shows me just "array"...

Comment: Hmmm ... Maybe there is a difference in the used editor. I spoke from a Java point of view (as I used Eclipse for Java development). So I thought, it will be the same for other editors in Eclipse also. If it does not, then I fear, I cannot help you. Sorry.

Comment: Ah! I learnt that this is called PHPDoc. I will update my answer

Comment: Hehe, I will tell my boss that we should rewrite the whole webapp in java :-)